# Connection Refused

Tags: proxy, port, git-clone

I'm getting the following error when I type `git clone --recursive https://github.com/projectname`:

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/projectname': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 1080 after 2057 ms: Connection refused`

I've been searching for the solution but I haven't find yet.

I also cloned repository with SSH key but while downloading the submodules I get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Check first your environment variables, looking for any `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY`.

For instance, at work, I have mine set to 127.0.0.1:3128, because I use an intermediate [local proxy **`px`**](https://github.com/genotrance/px), in order to avoid entering my credentials whenever I need to use the company proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I checked environment variables and I did not see any `HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY`, normally should there be one?

Comment: @Roshlex It can also be define in git config -l. Check for anything 'proxy, like a [`core.gitproxy`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coregitProxy) or more importantly: [`http.proxy`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpproxy)